# Php and PhantomJS

Tags: php, ubuntu, highcharts, phantomjs

First I install [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/build.html) and after i need to work with [highcharts-phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-phantomjs). Everything work fine if i use phantomjs form linux terminal ( Ubuntu 16.04) example:

```
phatomjs lib\highcharts-convert.js -infile pathToInFile.json -outfile pathToOutFile.jpg
```

but problem start when i use phantom in PHP code like

```
exec('phatomjs lib\highcharts-convert.js -infile pathToInFile.json -outfile pathToOutFile.jpg')
```

before this i change work directory so that is not problem!
If I execute this in PHP i get error

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Then i try with some solution from internet first add this in command:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM="offscreen"
```

but this don't render label in higcharts in both case (terminal and php program)!

After that i install xcb and try with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM="xcb"` but got same error from beginning

At the end i instal xvfb and run command with

```
exec('xvfb-run phatomjs lib\highcharts-convert.js -infile pathToInFile.json -outfile pathToOutFile.jpg')
```

but this drastically increase time,so time to render picture is more then 3s!

Is there some solution for this?

Comment: 3 seconds is quite ok for PhantomJS. Have you had better results previously?

Comment: Yes i had, if i use in direct in CLI php without xvfb-run time is less then second! Problem is this is only for one picture, but for some downloads i maybe will have 20+ charts!
And if i use QT_QPA_PLATFORM="offscreen" response is is about half second, phantom render data but label missing on chart! All chart after phatnom i render to PDF, but there is not speed problem cause if i use already made image time is acceptably!

Answer (score 0):

I now find somewhere that phantom team fix that available in beta version [phantom download](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/)! So someone can me help to first uninstall phantom or update, i didn't install with npm instead i use binary package following [install tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/rs63ea/installing-phantomjs-1-9-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64-x86)